# Android MVVM clean architecture with livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have an architectural question. Currently my app is so simple that user logs in and gets a list of restaurants and he can logout. I use kotlin coroutines for async part, mvvm live data and koin DI.

Here is my login flow when user clicks on login. The regex validation is done in `LoginViewModel` -

```
LoginFragment -> LoginViewModel -> AccountUseCase -> AccountRepoImpl -> AccountLocalDataSource or AccountRemoteDataSource
```

And the response is given all the way back from `DataSource to LoginFragment.`

I consider the `AccountUseCase` and `AccountRepoInterface` as a part of the domain folder along with the `AccountModel`. The `AccountRepoImpl` is in repo folder and `AccountLocalDataSource` and `AccountRemoteDataSource` is in datasource folder.

My question is ideally the domain should not have any 3rd party dependencies. But my `AccountUseCase` emits `livedata` to the viewmodel class and as a result my domain is using `android livedata` dependency and also it is not doing much but just calling the repo for loginuser. Does it make sense then to have this usecase?

Comment: Sounds like you don't need `AccountUseCase`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce why do u think so?

Comment: Because you already seem to have an AccountRepoImpl to do the same thing as the UseCase is doing. But maybe it's actually the Repo you don't need and what the UseCase could be doing.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes currently i dont need usecase but when my app gets bigger then I need a usecase

Comment: See https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/anemic-repositories-mvi-and-rxjava-induced-design-damage-and-how-aac-viewmodel-is-silently-1762caa70e13 :p add things when you actually need them

Comment: @EpicPandaForce very nice article by you, thank you :) just wanted to understand I am using Koin DI. So I inject viewModel in my fragment as by viewModel() and this you say should be replaced with AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory in order to obtain reference to SavedStateHandle. How would I do with Koin DI?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/55b693496fce1688617af6731407e2e3bab4a43c/koin-projects/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel.md#viewmodel-and-state-bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the `LiveData` dependency, I would suggest you to ignore it in this case. If you want to make it reactive, either you use library like `LiveData` or `RxJava` or have your own implementation. There's no much difference. Just that `LiveData` happen to be provided by a package that has the word `android` inside.

Regarding the use case, as you said your app is **currently** simple. The use case seems redundant for now as the logic is simple in this case but it will be helpful once the app gets more complex.

Some scenarios that I can think of:

- when the login logic changes, you only have to update the `AccountUseCase` which follows the Single Responsibility Pattern (SRP).
- when you want to use the `AccountUseCase` in other `ViewModel` instead of reusing the whole `LoginViewModel`.
- this makes your code base more consistent, if all the logic are inside the `domain layer`. Instead of "hiding" some simple logic inside your `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you so much. So do you think the structure I have follows clean architecture?

Comment: Interestingly when i change the phone configuration portrait to landscapethe login API call that was in progress stops and when config changed again, I am logged in

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on there without reading your code. Probably after configuration changed there is new API call made .